# Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core'

Tags: .net, .net-core, cil

I'm trying to compile a program from IL to exe on GNU/Linux, but can't explain how to dynlink `FSharp.Core.dll`. I tried to copy and paste it to the same directory where .exe is built, but no luck. I'm actually not sure where the issue can be: in my .il code, in my two JSON files or in the environment.

```
$ dotnet  --list-sdks
5.0.301 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I use `/usr/bin/ilasm testRepeat.il` to compile and `/usr/bin/dotnet ./testRepeat.exe` to run it. Output of compilation says that reference to FSharp.Core is added automatically

```
$ /usr/bin/ilasm testRepeat.il
Assembling 'testRepeat.il' , no listing file, to exe --> 'testRepeat.exe'

testRepeat.il : Warning -- Reference to undeclared extern assembly 'System.Runtime', adding.
testRepeat.il : Warning -- Reference to undeclared extern assembly 'FSharp.Core', adding.
testRepeat.il : Warning -- Reference to undeclared extern assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib', adding.
testRepeat.il : Warning -- Reference to undeclared extern assembly 'System.Console', adding.
Operation completed successfully
$ dotnet ./testRepeat.exe 
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'FSharp.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[1]    140195 IOT instruction (core dumped)  dotnet ./testRepeat.exe
```

.il and .json files are [here](https://gist.github.com/Kakadu/5b2a4cb0a7ed3e641997c76ecef12771)

Comment: @JL0PD log says that reference is added automatically...

Comment: if you want to write in IL, take a look at [`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.IL/) [how-to](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11411). It gives better user-experience than raw ilasm. I hope it will automatically handle assembly issues if you use `<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="your version" />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the dependencies should be mentioned in the '...deps.json' file. I needed to add following to make it work:

```
{
  ...
  "targets": {
      ...
      "FSharp.Core/5.0.0": {
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Core.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "5.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "5.0.20.50704"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```